# How to use both remote JSON files and local JSON files in React use i18next

Tags: i18next, react-i18next, i18next-http-backend

```js
i18next.use(ChainedBackend).init({
    backend: {
      backends: [
        HttpBackend, 
        resourcesToBackend((language, namespace) =>import(`./locales/${language}/${namespace}.json`))

      ],
      backendOptions: [{
        loadPath: 'http://xxx/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
      }]
    }
})
```

I want to use both remote JSON files and local JSON files, what should I do